# Windows Service can't run Stored procedure

Tags: c#, windows, stored-procedures, service, sqlclient

Alright, I've been looking at a bunch of other questions, but can't seem to find the right answer here...

I am writing a windows service in C# to run some data uploading into SQL Server Express with a stored procedure. The procedure is quite long, but it includes reading in data from TSV to temp table, then updating and inserting that data into a separate permanent table. Currently the stored procedure is fired off by a batch file run on windows task scheduler. I am trying to transition to a Windows service that will do this job and much more.

The problem that I am having, is that this stored procedure will not run from  the service. Here is the call I am using for the service:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("user id=reports; Password=*****; Integrated Security=false;" +
                                                "database=data_warehouse; Server=(serverName); ");


        try
        { conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog(ex);
        }

        SqlCommand GetSalesCount = new SqlCommand("select count (*) from [sales data] where EventEndDate = convert(date,getdate())");
        GetSalesCount.CommandTimeout = 0;
        GetSalesCount.Connection = conn;


        int? preCount = (int?)GetSalesCount.ExecuteScalar();

        Library.WriteErrorLog("started with " + preCount.ToString() + " records.");

        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("exec LoadSalesData", conn);
        sql.CommandTimeout = 0;

        try
        {
           sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog(ex);
        }


        // Getting the nuber of sales afterward
        SqlCommand getOffloadCount = new SqlCommand("Select count (*) from [sales data] where EventEndDate = convert(date,getdate())", conn);

        int? post = (int?)getOffloadCount.ExecuteScalar();

        Library.WriteErrorLog("Had " + post.ToString() + " records at End");

        conn.Close();
```

Now, This does not work. The code block completes, but No records update, i.e. the stored procedure doesn't run. If i save the result of the `executeNonQuery` i get (-1). IF i run the same `exec LoadSalesData` from smss with the same credentials, it works fine, can take up to 30 seconds to process.

I can replace the stored Procedure with another one that just loops through adding rows to a table for the same amount of time, and it runs just fine.

I am thinking it may have something to do with the request to run from the service, instead of ssms? Permissions? I'm not sure where to look.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the `exec` from you command and using `sql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` instead?

Comment: I have, yes. to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If neither `conn.Open` or `sql.ExecuteNonQuery` are throwing exceptions (apparently not, since you're getting a return value of -1) then most likely the procedure is executing. It's going to either execute the procedure or throw an exception because it either couldn't execute the procedure or the procedure itself raised an error. If none of that is happening then it's executing the procedure.

It sounds like you're determining that the procedure isn't executing because you don't see the expected result of the procedure. I'd consider the likelihood that the procedure is executing but not doing what's expected.

Or could you have more than one version of the procedure, and you're executing in one database but looking for the results in another database? That happens - you could verify which connection string you're using.

I'd put breakpoints on both `Library.WriteErrorLog(ex)` methods just to be absolutely sure that they aren't being reached (or just see if any errors are getting logged.) If there are no exceptions then the procedure is executing.

Sometimes something happens that appears to be impossible. When that happens it usually means that there's an incorrect assumption (or multithreading - not the case here.)

Comment: You are correct that I am assuming it did not run because the changes the procedure out to have made (in this case, increasing the number of record rows returned after it has run) do not happen. Nothing comes up in the logs either. I will try adding a break. Connection string is correct, since I can run a different stored procedure sucessfully from both ssms and the service... 
Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: *ought to have... it's been a long day.